# Python requests ODDITY

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to debug python request to scrap data from Amazon
but it always failed with error 503. I am compare to POST command from bash, the result always 200 OK. You can see in output, the request header is exacly the same, almost identical. Can any body expalain why ?

the script something like this

```
import requests
from http.client import HTTPConnection
HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

client = requests.session()
res = client.post( 'https://www.amazon.com/s/query',
      headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Chrome',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'deflate'
      },
      params = {'k': 'xbox'})
```

the output always with error 503

```
send: b'POST /s/query?k=xbox HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.amazon.com\r\nUser-Agent: Chrome\r\nAccept-Encoding: deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable\r\n'
header: Connection: keep-alive
header: Content-Length: 2671
header: server: Server
header: date: Wed, 15 Jun 2022 01:46:07 GMT
header: content-type: text/html
header: report-to: {"group": "nel", "max_age": 3600, "endpoints": [{ "url": "https://primary.prod.flex.frontier.a2z.com/nel"}, { "url": "https://secondary.prod.flex.frontier.a2z.com/nel"}]}
header: x-amz-rid: PRKZBYW6JNKFJ4221E28
header: vary: Content-Type,Accept-Encoding,X-Amzn-CDN-Cache,X-Amzn-AX-Treatment,User-Agent
header: last-modified: Mon, 25 Apr 2022 20:07:01 GMT
header: etag: "a6f-5dd801e82e340"
header: accept-ranges: bytes
header: strict-transport-security: max-age=47474747; includeSubDomains; preload
header: permissions-policy: interest-cohort=()
header: nel: { "report_to": "nel", "max_age": 3600, "success_fraction": 0.0, "failure_fraction": 1.0 }
header: x-served-by: cache-qpg1230-QPG
```

when I try using POST command from bash it always succeed :

```
POST 'https://www.amazon.com/s/query?k=xbox' \
-H 'Host: www.amazon.com' \
-H 'User-Agent: Chrome' \
-H 'Accept-Encoding: deflate' \
-H 'Accept: */*' \
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
-H 'Content-Length: 0' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-sSdE
```

the output:

```
POST https://www.amazon.com/s/query?k=xbox
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate
Host: www.amazon.com
User-Agent: Chrome
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: application/json

200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Wed, 15 Jun 2022 02:07:00 GMT
Server: Server
Vary: Content-Type,X-Amazon-Wtm-Tag-SP-Search-Secured-Port-Enabled,Accept-Encoding,X-Amzn-CDN-Cache,X-Amzn-AX-Treatment,User-Agent
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Type: application/json-amazonui-streaming;charset=UTF-8
Accept-Ch: ect,rtt,downlink,device-memory,sec-ch-device-memory,viewport-width,sec-ch-viewport-width,dpr,sec-ch-dpr
Accept-Ch-Lifetime: 86400
Client-Date: Wed, 15 Jun 2022 02:07:01 GMT
Client-Peer: 162.219.225.118:443
Client-Response-Num: 1
Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer: /C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/CN=DigiCert Global CA G2
Client-SSL-Cert-Subject: /CN=www.amazon.com
Client-SSL-Cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Client-SSL-Socket-Class: IO::Socket::SSL
Client-SSL-Version: TLSv1_3
Client-Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Nel: { "report_to": "nel", "max_age": 3600, "success_fraction": 0.0, "failure_fraction": 1.0 }
Permissions-Policy: interest-cohort=()
Report-To: {"group": "nel", "max_age": 3600, "endpoints": [{ "url": "https://primary.prod.flex.frontier.a2z.com/nel"}, { "url": "https://secondary.prod.flex.frontier.a2z.com/nel"}]}
Set-Cookie: session-id=138-2883811-7779558; Domain=.amazon.com; Expires=Thu, 15-Jun-2023 02:07:00 GMT; Path=/; Secure
Set-Cookie: session-id-time=2082787201l; Domain=.amazon.com; Expires=Thu, 15-Jun-2023 02:07:00 GMT; Path=/; Secure
Set-Cookie: i18n-prefs=USD; Domain=.amazon.com; Expires=Thu, 15-Jun-2023 02:07:00 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: sp-cdn="L5Z9:ID"; Version=1; Domain=.amazon.com; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Thu, 15-Jun-2023 02:07:00 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=47474747; includeSubDomains; preload
X-Amz-Rid: TG7103CWM9SZ51WTR8GJ
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Served-By: cache-qpg1279-QPG
X-Xss-Protection: 1;
```

as you can see the headers is identical. what make the python request different ?
thank you.

Comment: Your Python code results in a `200` status code when I run it.

Comment: I'm getting `200` as status and full data from your provided python snippet too.

Comment: Can a proxy be involved?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if you've figured out what causes this, but I've gotten a similar response with my C# call to Amazon. From my analysis this is happening at random for a few seconds to a few minutes where every call is corrupted with these extra fields. I've found just repeating the call after a bit will give the correct response. It's not a good solution, but it's a manageable one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).